# Bayesian statistics using Stata

Tags: statistics, bayesian

My question is regarding the following YouTube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F0QoMCSKJ4
(Introduction to Bayesian statistics, part 1: The basic concepts by StataCorp LLC)
In the above video at 4.22 mins
Posterior = Beta(34,36)
P(0.4 < theta < 0.499) = 0.434
Also find the attached screenshot of this calculation from the video.
When I tried to replicate the above
a)  In R

```
pbeta(0.499,34,36)-pbeta(0.4,34,36) 
= 0.5140403
```

b)  In Excel 2013

```
=BETA.DIST(0.499,34,36,1) - BETA.DIST(0.4,34,36,1) 
= 0.588551 - 0.074511
= 0.51404
```

I would like know why I am getting a different result from what was shown in the video.
Thanking in advance,

[Stata area calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHeRt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So you are quite correct in noticing that something was off here. While the mean they presented for the posterior distribution of `alpha / (alpha + beta) = 34/(34+36) = 0.4875`  was correct, they mistakenly did not update the prior while taking the probability within the (0.4,0.499) interval. That is the 0.434 value they calculate is based upon the `beta(30,30)` distribution. In stata the cumulative beta distribution is characterized by `ibeta(alpha,beta,theta)`. This is how they calculated P(0.4 < theta < 0.499) = 0.434:

```
disp ibeta(30,30,0.499) - ibeta(30,30,0.4)
.43429354
```

For a nice conversation on the intuition behind the beta distribution see the question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution).